# Why my Nginx proxy succeed to find my node webserver since my docker-compose doesn't expose any webserver port on the network?

Tags: docker, nginx

My node webserver uses express and listen on port 5500. 
My dockerfile-compose doesn't expose any port of my node webserver  (named webserver)  as following:

```
version: "3"

services:
 webserver:
  build: ./server
 form:
  build: ./ui
  ports:
   - "6800:80"
  networks:
      - backend  // i let the backend network just for legacy but in fact webserver isn't in this networks
  command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
networks:
```

backend:

My Nginx reverse proxy as following:

```
/request { 
proxy_pass http://webserver:5500/request 
}
```

expectation: y request have to fail because of the absence of shared network between the two services. 
result : request succeed.

I can't understand why ? maybe the default network between the container make the job ? 
more info: the request fails when the reverse_proxy redirect to a bad port, but succeed if the domain name is wrong and the port is good as following :

> proxy_pass http://webver:5500/request  > succeed

I can't understand the Nginx / Docker flow here. Someone would please explain to us what happens here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More recent versions of Docker Compose [create a Docker network automatically](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  Once that network exists, Docker provides its own DNS system so that containers can reach each other by name or network alias; Compose registers each service under its name in the YAML file, so within this set of containers, `webserver` and `form` would both be resolvable host names.

(The corollary to this is that you don't usually need to include a `networks:` block in the YAML file at all, and there's not much benefit to explicitly specifying a `container_name:` or manually setting container network settings.)